# Renumbering items in a list with SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

### The query:

```
$consulta = "UPDATE `list` 
                SET `pos` = $pos 
              WHERE `id_item` IN (SELECT id_item 
                                    FROM lists 
                                   WHERE pos = '$item' 
                                ORDER BY pos DESC 
                                   LIMIT 1)
                AND id_usuario = '$us' 
                AND id_list = '$id_pl'";
```

The thing is, this query is inside a foreach, and it wants to update the order of the items in a list.  Before I had it like this:

```
$consulta = "UPDATE `list` 
                SET `pos` = $pos
              WHERE `$pos` = '$item' 
                AND id_usuario = '$us' 
                AND id_list = '$id_pl'";
```

But when I update pos 2 -> 1, and then 1 -> 2, the result is two times 2 and no 1...

Is there  a solution for this query?

Comment: Even if it did support limit, you would still have the same issue.  You'd probably be better served with updating records without pos in the where clause, and update individual records, even if it requires a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renumbering the items in a list is tricky.  When you renumber the items in the list using multiple separate SQL statements, it is even trickier.

Your inner sub-select statement also is not properly constrained.  You need an extra condition such as:

```
AND id_list = '$id_pl'
```

There are probably many ways to do this, but the one that may be simplest follows.  I'm assuming that:

- the unshown `foreach` loop generates `$pos` values in the desired sequence (1, 2, ...)
- the value of `$id_pl` is constant for the loop
- the `foreach` loop gives values for `$us` and `$item` for each iteration
- the combination of `$id_pl`, `$us`, and `$item` uniquely identifies a row in the `list` table
- there aren't more than 100 `pos` values to worry about
- you are able to use an explicit transaction around the statement sequence

The suggested solution has two stages:

1. Allocate 100 + pos to each row to place it in its new position
2. Subtract 100 from each pos

This technique avoids any complicated issues about whether rows that have had there position adjusted are reread by the same query.

Inside the loop:

```
foreach ...
    ...$pos, $item, $us...

    UPDATE list 
       SET pos = $pos + 100
     WHERE id_item = '$item' 
       AND id_usuario = '$us' 
       AND id_list = '$id_pl'
       AND pos < 100
end foreach

UPDATE list
   SET pos = pos - 100
 WHERE id__list = '$id_pl';
```

If you don't know the size of the lists, you could assign negative pos values in the loop and convert to positive after the loop, or any of a number of other equivalent mappings.  The key is to update the table so that the new pos numbers in the loop are disjoint from the old numbers, and then adjust the new values after the loop.

Alternative techniques create a temporary table that maps the old numbers to the new and then executes a single UPDATE statement that changes the old pos value to the new for all rows in a single operation.  This is probably more efficient, especially if the mapping table can be generated as a query, but that depends on whether the renumbering is algorithmic.  The technique shown, albeit somewhat clumsy, can be made to work for arbitrary renumberings.

Comment: Man that's a clever solution! have been two hours thinking about this! i even created an 'updated' boolean field... lol!!!! thanks a million, should work, but still let you know! Just wondering (in spain means i haven't sleep for a while), what's going to happen if +100 items on list?

Comment: as I said, didn't sleep much. as you said, its required. What item count top would you say? i mean, this algorithm is tuff. 200?

Comment: @Toni: It depends on your data and how big your lists might.  If you don't know a safe upper bound (1 billion, perhaps?), then if the data type for `pos` is signed and there is no constraint to prevent you doing so, use the negative number trick mentioned in the answer.  All you need is for the two sets of numbers to be completely disjoint and an easy mapping for the second UPDATE operation.